# send audio file to a client and save it in it's device

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on node.js project , I am stuck in sending file from client to a  client and save it at device  receiver  , as same as whatsapp sending recording file from client to client .

### I try to send file by routing :

```
app.get('/music.mp3', function (req, res) {
    ms.pipe(req, res, "music.mp3");
});
```

but when the browser(client) receives  the file , it  starts  to play it .

### I need some ideas and instructions to start coding .

Comment: You want the file to be downloaded instead of playing? Use the `Content-Disposition` header

Comment: where i should use it "Content-Disposition: attachment" ??

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAbdullah why don't use just use res.download?

Comment: thanks @eenagy it works !!

Answer (score 3):

You want the file to be downloaded instead of played in the browser?

Then you should set the `Content-Disposition` header, below is a simple example with express:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.header({
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="download.txt"'
  });
  fs.createReadStream('file.txt').pipe(res);
}).listen(1234);
```

The above will start a server on port 1234, then serve the file `file.txt` as a download named `download.txt` when visiting the server.

Comment: unfortunately , I got the same  problem , the browser stills play the file automatically

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAbdullah Works fine for me with the above example, tested with a mp3 file as well. How are you using it?

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked , the problem was  in my server.js , it  was listening to port   by http not by express (app) , when I made  the app listening  , it works !!  thanks a lot

Comment: I am confused by this answer as it refers to `.txt` files and doesn't seem to reference the audio file anywhere.  I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @user1063287 substitute `file.txt` with your audio file.